# Human can't digest cellulose.....but the length of small intestine is approximately same in humans and herbivores

Tags: nutrition

My question is why herbivores are able to digest cellulose and why can't we??

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "digest". Herbivores aren't able to digest grass on their own, they keep bacteria in their guts to do that. Grass-eating herbivores also tend to have long digestive cycles and some have several stomach chambers.

In short, cellulose is a pain to digest.